# How to show a file name & line number pair in Chrome DevTools Styles section

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

got a problem with my Google Chrome (Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)) recently, please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Once you click on the right side, it shows like this:

[image]

I don's know since when and how it changed, but I really like the left side. any idea that I can change it back?

PLUS:

That is how I include the CSS files in my page:

```
<link href="mydomain.com/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Not like this:

```
<style>
/* some styles here */
</style>
```

Comment: It means your page uses an inline `style` tag, instead of `link` with a stylesheet URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your replay, I just edit my question, please take a look and see if that is what your mean?

Comment: Come on guys, Any ideas?

Comment: Your screenshot shows `style` elements, not `link`, which probably means there's something in your build process or a page script that does the conversion.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for your replay, I'm working with PHP, so it may not be converted during the build process, maybe some javascript does. I'm gonna check each of the scripts and will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Please, any ideas?

Comment: @wOxxOm It's been a while but you are right, one of the Javascript plugins did it.